# How to copy text of virtual terminal from graphics mode?

Tags: linux, terminal, paste, sabayon, chvt

Linux have virtual terminals, one can switch between them with `chvt 1`, `chvt 7` commands. Former is in the text mode, later is in the graphics mode.

I want to copy all the text from first terminal, with some utility from graphics mode.

`fbgrab -c 1 ~/image.png` saves an image, but in my case it is a transparent rectangle.

There is no ebuild for fbdump, so I can't check it. And actually I want some paste (as with `wgetpaste -s gists`), not a picture.

OS is Sabayon Linux with MATE DE on AMD GPU

I need this because my chrome browser starts to execute some js, and hangs the system (mouse cursor freezes), then there is a message in virtual terminal about crash in chrome plugin. I want to paste that message, but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from `/dev/vcs1` (for the first virtual console (tty1)).

```
cat /dev/vcs1
```

But chances are those lines are also in a log file. (check `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/kernel.log`, `/var/log/syslog` for a start).

You may also want to check the stdout/stderr of `chrome` which if you started it with your Windows manager, may be going to some file like `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: works! says `[5053968.102408] Chrome_ChildThr[18894]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000408727 sp 00007f5a631fe500 error 6 in plugin-container[400000+3b000]`

Comment: may be this - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205199